# CSRF Token missing error while trying to update database with fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to update the content of a database item using fetch. However, I get 403 Forbidden error in the console. I'm not using a form in my HTML template, just appending the elements to a div. The log says CSRF token missing.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

    const button = document.querySelectorAll("#edit_profile")
    button.forEach(function(button){
        button.onclick = function(){
      
            const memberID = button.dataset.id;
            const usernameID = button.dataset.username;
            const username = document.getElementById(`username_${memberID}`);

            let edit_username = document.createElement("textarea");
            edit_username.setAttribute("rows", "1");
            edit_username.innerHTML = username.innerHTML
            edit_username.id = `edit_username_${memberID}`;
            edit_username.className = `form-control username ${usernameID}`;

            const saveButton = document.createElement("button");
            saveButton.innerHTML = "Save";
            saveButton.id = `saveButton_${memberID}`;
            saveButton.className = "btn btn-success col-3";
            saveButton.style.margin = "10px";

            document.getElementById(`edit_${memberID}`).append(edit_username);
            document.getElementById(`edit_${memberID}`).append(saveButton);

            saveButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
                edit_username = document.getElementById(`edit_username_${memberID}`);

                fetch(`/edit_profile/${memberID}`,{
                    method: "POST",
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        username: edit_username.value,
                    })
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    if(result[`error`]){
                    reset(memberID)
                    } 
                    else {
                        username.innerHTML = result.username;
                        reset(memberID) 
                        
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                })
               
            })

        }
    });
```

Comment: Where is the backend code?

Comment: I would check the backend error log.

Comment: The 403 Forbidden response means the server understood the request but will not fulfill it. To understand why, we’d have to know more about the server’s expectations.

Comment: sorry, just edited the question. The log displays CSRF token missing. I tried to add the csrf token in HTML template but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: If your backend expects CSRF token, then before making a `fetch` request from the client you should get the token from your backend, and then add it to the appropriate part of the request (most often - a header) before accessing any other endpoints

Answer (score 0):

I added the following decorator in views.py and it solved the problem:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def edit_profile(request, member_id):
    if request.method != "POST":
        return JsonResponse({"error": "POST request required."}, status=400)
    team_members = Team.objects.get(id = member_id)

    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    body = json.loads(body_unicode)
    username = body['username']
    skills = body['skills']
    bio = body['bio']
    Team.objects.filter(id=member_id).update(username=f'{username}',skills=f'{skills}',bio=f'{bio}')
    return JsonResponse({"message": "Successful", "username": username, "skills": skills, "bio": bio}, status=200)
```

Comment: I'm not a Django expert, but I think it would make more sense to either: remove csrf from your backend completely if you don't require it; or keep it and make it work client-side. Your solution is just a haphazard fix. [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax) recommend adding csrf token to headers of the request